# Incremental input and assertion sets in Z3

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving

I have a program that runs Z3 version 4.8.8 - 64 bit, with incremental input: the program starts Z3 once, executes many rounds of input-output to Z3, and then stops Z3. For performance reasons, running Z3 without incremental input is not an option.

Each round, the program inputs some `(assert ...)` statements to Z3, inputs `(check-sat)` to Z3, then gets the output of `(check-sat)` from Z3.

I have two rounds of input-output: the first round of inputs is as in `z3.sat`:

```
(declare-fun f () Int)
(declare-fun n () Int)
(assert (< 1 n))
(assert (<= 2 f))
(assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
(assert (not false))
(check-sat)
```

which means: `f` is an even `Int` greater or equals to `2`.

And the second round of inputs is as in `z3.unsat`:

```
(declare-fun f () Int)
(declare-fun n () Int)
(assert (< 1 n))
(assert (<= 2 f))
(assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
(assert (not (exists ((alpha Int)) (= (* 2 alpha) f))))
(check-sat)
```

which means: if `f` is an even `Int` greater or equals to `2`, then there exists an `alpha` where `alpha=f/2`.

I assume that running Z3 with incremental input is similar to concatenating the two rounds of input, `z3.sat` and `z3.unsat`, into one input, as in `z3.combined`:

```
(declare-fun f () Int)
(declare-fun n () Int)
(assert (< 1 n))
(assert (<= 2 f))
(assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
(assert (not false))
(check-sat)
(declare-fun f () Int)
(declare-fun n () Int)
(assert (< 1 n))
(assert (<= 2 f))
(assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
(assert (not (exists ((alpha Int)) (= (* 2 alpha) f))))
(check-sat)
```

Running:

- `z3 -smt2 z3.sat` outputs `sat`
- `z3 -smt2 z3.unsat` outputs `unsat`
- `z3 -smt2 z3.combined` outputs errors, because the `(assert ...)` statements from the first round do not disappear:

  ```
  sat
  (error "line 8 column 21: invalid declaration, constant 'f' (with the given signature) already declared")
  (error "line 9 column 21: invalid declaration, constant 'n' (with the given signature) already declared")
  unknown
  ```

So it seems `(push 1)` and `(pop 1)` statements are needed for Z3 to forget previous assertion sets, so I added these statements at the start and end of `z3.sat` and `z3.unsat`, and re-concatenated `z3.pushpop.sat` and `z3.pushpop.unsat` to get `z3.pushpop.combined`.

- `z3.pushpop.sat`:

  ```
  (push 1)
  (declare-fun f () Int)
  (declare-fun n () Int)
  (assert (< 1 n))
  (assert (<= 2 f))
  (assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
  (assert (not false))
  (check-sat)
  (pop 1)
  ```
- `z3.pushpop.unsat`:

  ```
  (push 1)
  (declare-fun f () Int)
  (declare-fun n () Int)
  (assert (< 1 n))
  (assert (<= 2 f))
  (assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
  (assert (not (exists ((alpha Int)) (= (* 2 alpha) f))))
  (check-sat)
  (pop 1)
  ```
- `z3.pushpop.combined`:

  ```
  (push 1)
  (declare-fun f () Int)
  (declare-fun n () Int)
  (assert (< 1 n))
  (assert (<= 2 f))
  (assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
  (assert (not false))
  (check-sat)
  (pop 1)
  (push 1)
  (declare-fun f () Int)
  (declare-fun n () Int)
  (assert (< 1 n))
  (assert (<= 2 f))
  (assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
  (assert (not (exists ((alpha Int)) (= (* 2 alpha) f))))
  (check-sat)
  (pop 1)
  ```

However, now running:

- `z3 -smt2 z3.pushpop.sat` outputs `sat`
- `z3 -smt2 z3.pushpop.unsat` outputs `unknown`
- `z3 -smt2 z3.pushpop.combined` outputs:

  ```
  sat
  unknown
  ```

Why does `z3 -smt2 z3.pushpop.unsat` output `unknown`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Malte mentioned, the presence of pus/pop triggers "weaker" solvers in z3. (There are many technical reasons for this, but I agree from an end-user view-point, the change in behavior is unfortunate and can be rather confusing.)

But there are commands that let you do what you want without resorting to `push` and `pop`. Instead of it, simply insert:

```
(reset)
```

when you want to "start" a new session, and this will make sure it'll all work. That is, drop the `push`/`pop` and when you concatenate, insert a `(reset)` in between.

### A slightly better approach

While the above will work, in general you only want to forget assertions, but not definitions. That is, you want to "remember" that you have an `f` and an `n` in the environment. If this is your use case, then put the following at the top of your script:

```
(set-option :global-declarations true)
```

and when you want to "switch" to a new problem, issue:

```
(reset-assertions)
```

This way, you won't have to "repeat" the declarations each time. That is, your entire interaction should look like:

```
(set-option :global-declarations true)

(declare-fun f () Int)
(declare-fun n () Int)

(assert (< 1 n))
(assert (<= 2 f))
(assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
(assert (not false))
(check-sat)

(reset-assertions)

(assert (< 1 n))
(assert (<= 2 f))
(assert (= (+ (+ 1 f) 1) (+ n n)))
(assert (not (exists ((alpha Int)) (= (* 2 alpha) f))))
(check-sat)
```

which produces:

```
sat
unsat
```

### Reference

All of this is documented in the official [SMTLib document](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf). See Section 3.9, pg. 44, for the descripton of `global-declarations`, and Section 4.2.2, pg. 59, for the description of `(reset-assertions)`.

Answer (score 2):

Incremental mode forces Z3 to use different theory subsolvers, as explained by one of the developers in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28048025/491216). These "incremental mode" subsolvers are often less effective than the "regular" ones, or at least may behave differently. As far as I know, Z3 switches to incremental mode whenever an SMT program contains push-pop scopes or multiple check-sats.

You initially say that not using incremental mode is not an option, but at least your file `z3.pushpop.combined` looks easily splitable. Another option might be to reset Z3 (I think the SMT command `(reset)` exists for that purpose) in between, instead of having push-pop blocks. If what I claim above is correct, however, this wouldn't prevent Z3 from staying in non-incremental mode. You could consider asking the developers via a "question issue" on Z3's issue tracker.

Comment: Great, thank you for pointing out the consequences of being in "incremental mode".